# OracleLob sql server varbinary equivalent object for reading a VarBinary(max) C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

We've recently moved from oracle to ms sql server and I'm having trouble reading a VarBinary(max) from SQL Server

The code for oracle was

```
    private byte[] CallSelectBlob(string aSqlCommand)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[0];
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(aSqlCommand, oc);
        OracleDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string fieldName = reader.GetName(i);
                OracleLob myLob = reader.GetOracleLob(i);
                if (!myLob.IsNull)
                {
                    byte[] b = new byte[myLob.Length];
                    myLob.Read(b, 0, Convert.ToInt32(myLob.Length));
                    result = b;
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

And that worked well, but I can't manage to find an object that can replace OracleLob to something that can work with VarBinary(max) ( which will serve as a pdf file)

The function should return it as a byte[].

Does anyone know a way that could work to achieve this?

Comment: Please only use IDE tags for questions about the tool itself, not for general code questions. Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: `SqlDataReader.GetBytes`. There's also `SqlDataReader.GetStream` for streaming access.